# Tumblr, How to see who uploaded a photo

Tags: tumblr, photos, upload, profile

Is there any way to see a Tumblr profile with just the photos/videos/notes uploaded by the user and not everything that was reblogged?

Answer (score 1):

You can go to this [site](http://www.studiomoh.com/fun/tumblr_originals/) and just key in your Tumblr name.

Sample output:

[image]